# Authenticating wordpress from an external app Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor, webassembly, wordpress-login

There is a website on wordpress.
User registration is performed on the site, accounts are stored in the site database.
It is necessary to authenticate users from an external application (Blazor WASM) using the system and the site database, after which, in case of successful authorization, the user will be able to work in an external application.

How can this be done using http requests?

Comment: I'm sorry, I typed it wrong, Razor - it must be Blazor

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on a few things -

1. Are you hosting the WASM app on a separate domain? If so, you will need to configure CORS on the server.
2. How are you maintaining the authenticated session? Cookies? JSON Web Tokens (JWT)? Custom access token or id?

You will need to include the `authorization` header with all HTTP requests to ensure the user is still authorized to access you app. Luckily, with Blazor WASM there is a very easy way to add this header to all outgoing HTTP requests using a custom implementation of `AuthorizationMessageHandler`. Here's an example that I personally use this exact code successfully in my own Blazor WASM app:

```cs
public class CorsAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public CorsAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider, 
       NavigationManager navigation) : base(provider, navigation)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(
            authorizedUrls: new[] { "https://api.myapp.com" }
        );
    }
}
```

Here's it being added to a `HttpClient` in `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(
    "Private.ServerAPI", 
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.myapp.com")
).AddHttpMessageHandler<CorsAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Unfortunately, this is not exactly what I'm looking for.
Not a problem with WASM, the problem is how to get the authentication confirmation from the WP site

Comment: I'm confused then, so you aren't using Blazor WASM? If you are trying to verify authorization in PHP, just use the headers/session variables.

Comment: My app is Blazor WASM. 
Accounts are stored in WP site DB.
User registration is performed on the site, accounts are stored in the site database. It is necessary to authenticate users from Blazor WASM app using the system and the site database, after which, in case of successful authorization, the user will be able to work in an Blazor WASM application.

Comment: Okay so that means you will have to setup JWT generation on the PHP side.

Comment: I need only confirmation of login/password from the WP site, I'm looking the way to connect to the site, send request and get reply

Comment: The proper way to do this would be setting a cookie for the WP/PHP session after logon (which it already will do) then using that cookie in all web requests from the WASM client to your WP server

Comment: How to connect to WP site API?
Where to send request?